# Is "einiges" equivalent to "some things"?

Tags: grammar, style

> Ich habe ***einiges*** in meinem Wagen vergessen. Ich komme gleich zurück.

I forgot some things in my car. I'll be back in a second.

> Ich hatte früher viele CDs der Beatles. ***Einiges*** davon habe ich verlegt.

I used to have many Beatle Cds. Some of them i have misplaced.

Do you have any alternatives for "einiges" ?

Comment: Except that it needs to be "Einige" in the second example (because CDs is plural), the sentences are grammatically correct and will be understood.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Einige* can be translation for some but in many cases *ein paar* is the better choice.

> Ich habe ein paar Sachen im Auto vergessen.
>
> Ich hatte früher viele Panthera Cds. Ein paar davon habe ich verloren.

The thing is, that *einige* also means "quite a few". This is clear when it comes with a strong emphasis.

> Ich muss noch EINIGES lernen.

This is quite far from

> I have to learn SOME things.

Even without the emphasis, this second meaning is kind of there and especially in writing I would be tempted to take it for a "quite a few" as a first guess. That's why *ein paar* is preferable.

Side note: Using *verlegen* with books and CDs is an unlucky choice because the verb also means *to publish*. I'd go for

> Ein paar davon finde ich nicht mehr./sind irgendwie weg.

Answer (score 3):

*einige-* = some

For the first one, I think you'd just say

> Ich habe etwas im Auto vergessen (=I forgot something in the car)

or

> Ich habe einige Dinge im Auto vergessen (=I left some things in the car)

As for the 2nd one, *einige-* is a [declinable word specifically a plural indefinite article](http://www.german-grammar.de/grammar/chapter_11/11_2_declension_indefinite_articles.htm) so in this example there are multiple CDs so it gets an -e

> Einige davon habe ich verlegt. (=I've misplaced some of them)